# Backspace doesnt work on Input box of PrimeNG when integrated to third party application

Tags: input, angular8, primeng, web-component, primeng-datatable

I am creating basic component using PrimeNG. I have added input box on my component as:

```
<input type="text" style="width:8vw"/>
```

If I run component individually, input box works fine. However, when I integrate this component in my AngularJS based application, then backspace on input box doesn't work. Other strokes like key entries, delete etc works well.

P.S.: Input box is actually filter of my primeNG table component. I have tried input box outside grid and asking accordingly for simplicity. Grid populates correctly as well when I integrate component but just backspace on filterbox doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was poor coding in my client application. Someone had captured backspace keycode event and just returned to prevent browser back on application. Stopping event propagation on my component solved the issue.